# C++ library for working with probability distributions

Tags: gratis, open-source, library, software-development, statistics

I want a C++ library which would allow me to dynamically construct a distribution, from a wide selection of distribution families, with its appropriate parameters, based on configuration data read from disk or from console (rather than deciding which distribution it is at compile-time, i.e. not just selection via template parameters). I need to be able to use this constructed distribution to (relatively) efficiently generate large amounts of data.

Requirements:

- Libre
- Gratis
- Available for Linux and Windows
- Ability to create composed distributions from existing ones (e.g. the application of some f: R^2->R to pairs of random variables with known distributions).

Desirable:

- Support for explicitly-specified distributions over small finite domains
- Support for distributions over complex numbers
- Support for distributions over more complicated types (variants, tuples, optionals etc.)
- C++17, or at least C++11
- Known to work with many compilers, including clang, gcc and msvc
- No Boost dependencies
- Used in more than toy projects
- Actively maintained
- Plays nice with the standard library distributions

Don't care:

- Compiled or header-only
- Pseudorandom or using hardware entropy sources

Comment: look to R ... searcg for R CRAN C++

Answer (score 0):

C++11 includes a number of statistical distributions without a Boost requirement:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

For composing or mixing distributions, see this example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320025/mixture-of-gaussian-distribution-in-c

This should be all that you need. If not, there is a header-only library containing a number of other useful statistical distributions here:

https://github.com/kthohr/stats

The same author also has C++ MCMC and optimization libraries.